# Как исправить ошибку с post запросом?

Tags: html, python, django

У меня есть django сервер, который должен по нажатия на кнопку send message отправлялось сообщение, а потом переходило в новое окно с надписью "отправлено". Но при её нажатии я перехожу на страницу с ошибкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как эту ошибку исправить? Она возникает даже если написать ссылку на страницу `action = "/wassent/"`
Ниже все коды.

Код html:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message">
</form>
```

Код views:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .forms import ContactForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
            recipients = ['somemail@mail.ru']
            send_mail(subject, message+sender, 'somemail@mail.ru', recipients)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'audio/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Очевидно, ваш почтовый сервер по каким-то причинам не работает. Он у вас вообще есть и настроен ли?

Comment: Я не видел описания почтового сервера. Просто добавил этот код. Если его надо настроить то как?

Comment: Установка и настройка самого́ почтового сервера никак не касается джанги. Возможно, вам будет проще просто подключить почту Google или Яндекс вместо установки своего сервера. Для настройки подключения джанги к почтовому серверу пропишите соответствующие настройки https://tproger.ru/translations/email-functionality-django/

Comment: Настройка подключения это же и есть причина этой ошибки. Или я не прав?

Comment: Настроек подключения вы не показали, поэтому фиг знает

Comment: Они же в setting.py?

Comment: Да, вон по ссылке написано что там нужно настраивать

Comment: Хорошо. Сейчас  настрою, проверю

Comment: Пишет : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Audio.apps'
Где Audio та аппликация, откуда будет производится отправка

Comment: Хм, какую-то неправильную ссылку я вам дал) Это не нужно, самое главное — семь первых строчек настроек из раздела «Изменение настроек проекта» *(блин, почему в интернете нет нормальных инструкций по почте в Django? Хоть самому брать и статью писать)*

Comment: В документации Django про почту и про нужные настройки написано без лишней воды, однако без конкретных инструкций https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/email.html

Comment: Я как раз с этого сайта брал код

Comment: Нужно не бездумно брать код, а ещё и внимательно читать всё, что написано возле него, особенно начиная с «Письмо отправлено через SMTP хост и порт, которые указаны в настройках...»

Comment: Да. Эта ошибка хоть и пропала, но появилось: страница wassend не найдена. Хотя в каждом urls она прописана

Comment: Во-первых, определитесь, wassend или wassent, во-вторых, похоже это уже никак не касается данного вопроса

Comment: Я везде проверил. Поменял wassent на wassend, но так и осталось

Comment: Фиг вас знает, что вы там творите, если кода не показываете

Comment: Так а что показывать-то?) Я добавил только настройки почты.

Comment: Это явно не имеет никакого отношения к почте, похоже вы запутались в собственном коде

Comment: Бывает. Спасибо